# Check how many hours/days passed

Tags: c#, datetime, time

---

I'm trying to make a function to give an award every hour and every day.

For that I want to implement a function that given 2 DateTime check how many hours/days passed.

I already have a Coroutine to call that function every second.

For example, I want to give awards every 00:00:00, 01:00:00 ... 12:00:00 ...  23:00:00

---

**Example:**

```
DateTime date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 20, 59, 59);
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 21, 0, 0);
int hoursPassed = (int) date1.Subtract(date0).TotalHours;
Debug.Log("Hours "+ hoursPassed);
```

---

The hoursPassed will be equal to 0 in this case. I want to make a function (maybe already exists) that retrieve me 1 instead. The same with the days.

---

**Example 2**

```
DateTime date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 23, 59, 59);
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 10, 00, 00, 00);
    int DaysPassed = (int) date1.Subtract(date0).TotalDays;
    Debug.Log("Days "+ DaysPassed);
```

---

It will retrieve 0 and I want to retrieve 1.

---

I also want this to work when multiple hours/days have passed .

---

**Can anybody help me?**

Thank you

Comment: if (hoursPassed == 0) {hoursPassed = 1}

Comment: When you have 9:30 and 10:40 on the same day, do you want 1 hour as a result or 2 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create *trimmed* `DateTime` variables by stripping minutes/seconds when interested in hours only and by trimming hours/minutes/seconds when interested in days only. Then calculate the difference in hours or days.

```
// Calculates the number of hour strikes between the two given times
public static int HourStrikesBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    if(from > to)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("from must not be after to");
    }

    // Trim to hours
    DateTime fromTrimmed = new DateTime(from.Year, from.Month, from.Day, from.Hour, 0, 0);
    DateTime toTrimmed = new DateTime(to.Year, to.Month, to.Day, to.Hour, 0, 0);

    int hours = (int)(toTrimmed - fromTrimmed).TotalHours;

    return hours;
}

// Calculates the number of midnights between the two given times
public static int MidnightsBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    if (from > to)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("from must not be after to");
    }

    // Trim to days
    DateTime fromTrimmed = new DateTime(from.Year, from.Month, from.Day);
    DateTime toTrimmed = new DateTime(to.Year, to.Month, to.Day);

    int days = (toTrimmed - fromTrimmed).Days;

    return days;
}
```

Sample:

```
DateTime date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 20, 59, 59);
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 21, 0, 0);
int hourspassed = HourStrikesBetween(date0, date1);  // = 1

date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 20, 00, 00);
date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 21, 50, 0);
hourspassed = HourStrikesBetween(date0, date1);  // = still 1

date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 20, 59, 59);
date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 22, 10, 0);
hourspassed = HourStrikesBetween(date0, date1);  // = 2


date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 23, 59, 59);
date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 10, 00, 00, 00);
int daysPassed = MidnightsBetween(date0, date1);  // = 1
```

Note that this will only work when crossing Dayligth Saving Time boundaries if you consistently use UTC DateTime instead of Local DateTime.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm not sure yet but I want to use a server to return me the specific DateTime depending on the timezone.
Do you have any suggestion about a site that provides that  ?

Comment: @GoncaloDiogo Don't use local times. Use UTC to calculate time differences. Otherwise you will get in trouble when clients move through different time zones or cross Daylight Saving Time boundaries. Then only convert UTC to local time for displaying it if necessary.

Comment: @GoncaloDiogo I don't think you will find a reliable service that you can query unlimited for free.

Comment: Yeah, probably I have to pay or do my own server. I think if I find a proper server (paid ofc) I can get the UTC time and I wont have problems! Thank you anyway man :) If you know any proper paid service you can recommend

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
private static int GetHours(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    return Math.Max(0, Convert.ToInt32((date1 - date2).TotalMinutes / 60 + ((date1 - date2).TotalMinutes % 60 > 0 ? 1 : 0)));
}
```

Usage:

```
    DateTime date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 20, 59, 59);
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 21, 0, 0);                        
    Console.Write(GetHours(date1, date0).ToString());
```

Returns 1

Spanning more than a day:

```
    DateTime date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 20, 59, 59);
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 10, 21, 0, 0);                       
    Console.Write(GetHours(date1, date0).ToString());
```

Returns 25

Comment: When using for example 9:30 and 10:40, this code returns two hours as a result. But I think the question wants to have only 1 hour difference in that case because only one hour strike was passed.

Comment: @NineBerry - What makes you think that?

Comment: Yeah! I tested with 9:30 and 10:40 and it returned 2 instead of 1 (10:00)

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that `Math.Ceiling` is the easiest way to make this work:

Example:

```
DateTime date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 20, 59, 59);
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 21, 0, 0);
int hoursPassed = (int)Math.Ceiling(date1.Subtract(date0).TotalHours);
Console.WriteLine("Hours " + hoursPassed);
```

Example 2:

```
DateTime date0 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 9, 23, 59, 59);
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2018, 8, 10, 00, 00, 00);
int DaysPassed = (int)Math.Ceiling(date1.Subtract(date0).TotalDays);
Console.WriteLine("Days "+ DaysPassed);
```